# Is this nameof() truly a recursive call?

Tags: c#, recursion, resharper, nameof

I'm making a ConfigurationSection in C# right now. I decided to take advantage of some C# 6 features by using nameof(PropertyName) instead of hard coded strings.

However, I'm getting a weird result from Resharper about a recursive call.

Here's an example:

[image: Recursive Warning]

I can see why it might give this warning, as the property is being referenced within itself. I'm not convinced however that this is *actually* recursive.

Is there anything I have to worry about with this call?

Comment: Sounds like a resharper bug to me.  Add a breakpoint on line 35 and step through it in the debugger and you'll know if it's recurring or not if it stops on the nameof(CoreApiRootUrl) more than once.

Comment: nameof kind of sounds like short hand code for using reflection to do it, probably how they wrote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless `this[string]` calls `CoreApiRootUrl`, then it's not recursive.

You're right that `nameof(...)` doesn't actually make a call at all.

I've just validated that I see the same bug (with R# 10.0.1) in a small test class:

```
public class Bug
{
    public string this[string x] => "";

    public string Foo
    {
        get { return this[nameof(Foo)]; } // Warning here
    }
}
```

Oddly enough, if I change `Foo` to an expression-bodied property:

```
public string Foo => this[nameof(Foo)];
```

I don't see the warning.

Definitely a R# bug - file it with Jetbrains.

Comment: Looks like it's fixed in 10.0.2. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-450555